# Best way to modify strings in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm currently writing a test bench for a VHDL design I made and I need to write a message to a text file. The message is of the format

```
[instance_name];[simulation_time]
```

(i.e. `U0;700 ns`) and the filename must be `[instance_name].log`. Getting the instance name and simulation time is no problem, but writing to a custom filename has been problematic. Under simulation, the instance name will be given in the format:

```
"U0\ComponentX\test\"
```

and I would like to replace the slashes with underscores. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our [PoC Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC) has quite a big collection on string operations/functions. There is a `str_replace` function in [PoC.strings](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/strings.vhdl#L696-L712) that should solve your question. There is also the [PoC.utils](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/utils.vhdl) package with non string related functions, that could also be helpful in handling strings and file I/O.

A simple implementation:

```
function replace(str : STRING) return STRING
  variable Result : STRING(str'range) := str;
begin
  for i in str'range loop
    if (Result(i) = '\') then
      Result(i)  := '_';
    end if;
  loop;
  return Result;
end function;
```

Usage:

```
constant original : STRING := "U0\ComponentX\test\";
constant replaced : STRING := replace(original);
```

Comment: Thanks! Does the Function go inside the `Architecture` declaration, before the `begin` statement?

Comment: You can declare it between architecture and it's begin or in a package if multiple architectures need this function.

Answer (score 2):

Simple replace character function that is a bit more versatile and does the same job would be (nothing wrong with @Paebbels's answer)

```
      function fReplaceChar(
        a : character;
        x : character;
        s : string) return string
      is
        variable ret : string(s'range) := s;
      begin
        for i in ret'range loop
          if(ret(i) = a) then
            ret(i) := x;
          end if;
        end loop;
        return ret;
      end function fReplaceChar;
```

If there are more than one character to replace, one can always stack the function:

```
  function fReplaceChar(
    a : character;
    b : character;
    x : character;
    s : string) return string
  is
  begin
    return fReplaceChar(b, x, fReplaceChar(a, x, s));
  end function fReplaceChar;
```

or function call:

```
 fReplaceChar(')','_',fReplaceChar(':','(','_',tb'instance_name));
```

So for example:

```
 process 
 begin
     report lf & tb'instance_name & lf &
     fReplaceChar(')','_',fReplaceChar(':','(','_',tb'instance_name));
     wait;
 end process;
```

gives:

> # ** Note: 
>   # :tb(sim): 
>   # _tb_sim__

Comment: I think I have written such a generic version for complete strings in PoC :). You seem to have a broad knowledge of VHDL. Are you interested in open source work e.g. on PoC or CoreLib?