# How to convert integer to string with leading zeros in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl

How to print integers with leading zeros in VHDL?

In essence to achieve same as in C or Python:

```
printf("%05d", number);
str(number).zfill(5)
```

Naturally, this would be for simulation only (writing to file or reports etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the VHDL way. Write one to_dstring function that works universally:

```
use std.textio.all;

entity rightjustd is
end entity;

architecture foo of rightjustd is
    type filltype is (NOFILL, ZEROFILL);
    function to_dstring (
        value:      in integer;
        field:      in width := 0;
        just:       in side := RIGHT;
        fill:       in filltype := NOFILL
    ) return string is
        variable retstr: string (1 to field);
    begin
        if field = 0 then
            return integer'image(value);
        elsif field < integer'image(value)'length then 
            retstr := (others => '#');
        elsif fill = NOFILL  or just = LEFT then
            retstr := justify (integer'image(value), just, field);
        else  -- fill = ZEROFILL and just = RIGHT, field >= image length
            retstr  := justify (integer'image(abs value), just, field);
            for i in retstr'range loop
                if retstr(i) = ' ' then
                    retstr(i) := '0';
                end if;
            end loop;
            if value < 0 then
                retstr(1) := '-';
            end if;
        end if;
        return retstr;
    end function to_dstring;
begin
    process
    begin
        report to_dstring(-2456, 12, RIGHT, ZEROFILL);
        report to_dstring(-2456, 4, RIGHT, ZEROFILL);
        report to_dstring(-2456);
        report to_dstring(-2456, 12, LEFT, ZEROFILL) & '.';
        report to_dstring(-2456, 12, RIGHT);
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

This hasn't been thoroughly tested. The test cases produce:

```
rightjustd.vhdl:38:9:@0ms:(report note): -00000002456
rightjustd.vhdl:39:9:@0ms:(report note): ####
rightjustd.vhdl:40:9:@0ms:(report note): -2456
rightjustd.vhdl:41:9:@0ms:(report note): -2456       .
rightjustd.vhdl:42:9:@0ms:(report note):        -2456
```

The initial values for the (class constant) inputs mean you can leave arguments off from right to left all the way to just supplying an integer value.

The justify function call requires -2008 and is declared in package textio.

Comment: Wow, I learned 3 new things from this example. I think this is SOF at its best. 1) justify function, 2) that you can "auto-overload" with default values in function. 3) textio types can have useful re-use. What I don't quite understand is why you have direction in function parameter. I was once taught "A function can only have input parameters, so the mode (direction) is not specified" and haven't questioned it since.

Comment: The mode is implicit and only *in*, but can be specified explicitly. [VHDL-2017](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/VHDL_2017) will allow also *out* modes in [impure functions](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/TopLCS2016_002).

Answer (score 2):

So far, the best way I've come up with is this function:

```
-- Range is limited to from 1 to 9 as 10 digit
-- integer can already overflow in VHDL
function fIntToStringLeading0 (a : natural; d : integer range 1 to 9) return string is
  variable vString : string(1 to d);
begin
  if(a >= 10**d) then
    return integer'image(a);
  else
    for i in 0 to d-1 loop
      vString(d-i to d-i) := integer'image(a/(10**i) mod 10);
    end loop;
    return vString;
  end if;
end function;
```

For examle:

```
  process  is
    variable number : integer := 42;
  begin
    report fIntToStringLeading0(number, 5);
    wait;
  end process;
```

Outputs:

> # ** Note: 00042

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source package aiming for C style formatting. You'll find it here https://github.com/suoto/hdl_string_format

Comment: This is not very useful answer, as it doesn't educate how this is done and further requires you to go to your library and seek what function you refer to in this case - so at least please mention the function with examples that does _exactly_ what was in question. Also, your library had GPL3 license that practically prevents the commercial use of it - with the self-promotion, it would be courteous to mention the license in the answer, e.g. "open source package (GPL3) aiming...".

Comment: Fair enough. This is more an answer if you ever want to do some more C style formatting than zero filling. If that's the case you would need to read THEIR, NOT MINE, manual, license conditions etc to figure out the details and if that fits your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another idea that gets rid of the check to make sure that any leading zeroes are required by using the TEXTIO write procedure, which does that kind of checking. The trouble is, the write procedure puts in leading spaces not zeroes and substituting zeroes in for spaces is clunky:

```
  function fIntToStringLeading0 (a : natural; d : integer range 1 to 9) return string is
    variable L : line;
  begin
    write(L,a,right,d);
    for I in 1 to L.all'length loop
      if L.all(I) = ' ' then
        L.all(I) := '0';
      end if;
    end loop;
    return L.all;
  end function;
```

eg

```
use std.textio.all;

entity LEADING_ZEROES is
end entity ;

architecture LEADING_ZEROES of LEADING_ZEROES is
  function fIntToStringLeading0 (a : natural; d : integer range 1 to 9) return string is
    variable L : line;
  begin
    write(L,a,right,d);
    for I in 1 to L.all'length loop
      if L.all(I) = ' ' then
        L.all(I) := '0';
      end if;
    end loop;
    return L.all;
  end function;
begin

  process
  begin
    report fIntToStringLeading0(1234,5);
    report fIntToStringLeading0(12345,6);
    report fIntToStringLeading0(12345,3);
    wait;
  end process;

end architecture LEADING_ZEROES;
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/39di

Comment: I do like this one. Instead of 1 to L.all'length you could have L.all'range. Which reminds me of [fReplaceChar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631356/best-way-to-modify-strings-in-vhdl/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a two-liner:

```
  ZEROES := (others => '0');
  ZEROES(ZEROES'length-integer'image(N)'length+1 to ZEROES'length) := integer'image(N);
```

eg

```
entity LEADING_ZEROES is
end entity ;

architecture LEADING_ZEROES of LEADING_ZEROES is
begin

  process
    constant MAXLENGTH : integer := 10;
    variable N : integer;
    variable ZEROES : string(1 to MAXLENGTH);
  begin
    N := 1234;
    ZEROES := (others => '0');
    ZEROES(ZEROES'length-integer'image(N)'length+1 to ZEROES'length) := integer'image(N);
    report ZEROES;
    wait;
  end process;

end architecture LEADING_ZEROES;
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4B84

It's probably better to wrap it up in a function like yours and add your checking:

```
  function fIntToStringLeading0 (a : natural; d : integer range 1 to 9) return string is
    variable vString : string(1 to d) := (others => '0');
  begin
    if(a >= 10**d) then
      return integer'image(a);
    else
      return vString(1 to vString'length-integer'image(a)'length) & integer'image(a);
    end if;
  end function;
```

eg

```
entity LEADING_ZEROES is
end entity ;

architecture LEADING_ZEROES of LEADING_ZEROES is
  function fIntToStringLeading0 (a : natural; d : integer range 1 to 9) return string is
    variable vString : string(1 to d) := (others => '0');
  begin
    if(a >= 10**d) then
      return integer'image(a);
    else
      return vString(1 to vString'length-integer'image(a)'length) & integer'image(a);
    end if;
  end function;
begin

  process
  begin
    report fIntToStringLeading0(1234,5);
    report fIntToStringLeading0(12345,6);
    report fIntToStringLeading0(12345,3);
    wait;
  end process;

end architecture LEADING_ZEROES;
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/255x

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just wanted to

```
printf("%05d", number);  // in C
```

into

```
print("%05d" % number)   # in python
```